# Import Excel Sheet

Tags: asp.net

I want to Upload File but on Click if i chose the browze file and then click it displays `Page not found error` I want to Upload File but on Click if i chose the browze file and then click it displays Page not found error but when i click the upload button without choosing a file it redirect me to the page and throughs exception `could not find a part of a path` In Asp.net C#

```
protected void UploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {

                string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelSheets/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the browser url when it displays that error?

Comment: The connection to localhost was interrupted.http://localhost:4235/Import.aspx

Answer (score 1):

shoudnt be this

```
if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
```

change to this

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
```

you are trying to save the file when there is no file to upload

Comment: is there a PostBackUrl Set somewhere? check properties of all your controls.